# flutter: HiveError: Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?

Tags: flutter-hive

[Screen shot of my hive service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGuT4.png)

This is my hive service, I called the initializeHive() method in the main function but I still get the same error when I try to use the addData() method.

I did everything but still get the same error please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  List<WordModel> wordList = [];
  late final Box<WordModel> _hiveWords;
  Box<WordModel> get getHiveBox => _hiveWords;
  

  Future<void> initializeHive() async {
    await Hive.initFlutter();
    Hive.registerAdapter(WordModelAdapter());

    _hiveWords = await Hive.openBox<WordModel>("hiveWords");
  }  

  

Future<void> addData(WordModel word) async =>_hiveWords.add(word);
```